# Aspects not being woven in Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka, aspectj

I am trying to weave a message in the source code, by making use of :

```
@Before(value = "call (* *.tell(..))") def printSample(): Unit = {
    logger.info("Message ")
  }
```

which (I hope it) means that for any call of a function tell(..), a logger info message is outputted on screen console.

This is the class  where the tell function is being used :

```
import akka.actor._

case object PingMessage

case object PongMessage

case object StartMessage

case object StopMessage

/**
 * An Akka Actor example written by Alvin Alexander of
 * http://alvinalexander.com
 *
 * Shared here under the terms of the Creative Commons
 * Attribution Share-Alike License: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/
 *
 * more akka info: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html
 */
class Ping(pong: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  var count = 0

  def incrementAndPrint {
    count += 1; println("ping")
  }

  def receive: Receive = {
    case StartMessage =>
      incrementAndPrint
      pong ! PingMessage
    case PongMessage =>
      incrementAndPrint
      if (count > 99) {
        sender ! StopMessage
        println("ping stopped")
        context.stop(self)
      } else {
        sender ! PingMessage
      }
  }
}

class Pong extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case PingMessage =>
      println("  pong")
      sender ! PongMessage
    case StopMessage =>
      println("pong stopped")
      context.stop(self)
  }
}

object PingPongTest extends App{
  val system = ActorSystem("PingPongSystem")
  val pong = system.actorOf(Props[Pong], name = "pong")
  val ping = system.actorOf(Props(new Ping(pong)), name = "ping")
  // start them going
  ping.tell(StartMessage,ping)
}
```

Yet the aspect is not being weaved, i.e. the logger output, is not being outputted to the console.

Can somebody help me understand what could be wrong please ?

***EDIT :*** The code snippet above is in a calling class, i.e. the main class of the project, calls the creation of a new Process, which main purpose is to execute the code snippet above. This is done with the help of `Process("java PingPong").!`.

The Main Class involves :

```
object SCHMLLauncher {
  val actorSystem: ActorSystem[Any] = ActorSystem(Behaviors.empty, "system")
  var TracerRef: ActorRef[Any] = _
  var first: Boolean = true
  val schml = new SCHML

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    logger.info("Starting System to be monitored.")
    sleep(5000)
    Process("java PingPong").!
 }
}
```

Comment: Just edited the question some further code explanations. Hope this helps you understand better my system :)

Comment: Same style of asking questions, same kind of comment: Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, then **edit** (not delete and duplicate, like last time) the question in order to become one. I want to see full classes with imports, package names etc. AOP pointcuts are sensitive to package names and class structure. You also did not mention if you use binary weaving during compilation or load-time weaving. That makes a big difference in how you need to start the external process. Do you ever read documentation, by the way? Your many questions here that imply you don't.

Comment: Hi. I have just updated some further code samples. To answer the question related to whether it is compile-time or load-time weaving, I am currently working with compile-time, but I do not know whether it is applicable for my project 100%. Thanks again :)

Comment: Well, you use Scala, so you probably use binary weaving like we made it work together in your first question a while ago. From the setup there you should remember that in order to run a program with compiled-in AspectJ aspects, you need to put `aspectjrt.jar` on the classpath, otherwise you should see errors during start-up. I do not see that when you start the process. For the last time: Publish an **MCVE** on GitHub, if you want better help. Otherwise I am just going to stop answering your questions. With all due respect, it is too tedious to guess all the time, despite your update.